# Pickle loads not working after upgrade to mac os catalina

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, macos-catalina

I have simple code to load a serialized pickled file that was working fine before I upgraded to macos Catalina.  Now when I run the code in an iPython console in Spyder the console restarts at line 1, all variables are cleared and there is no error message.  There's no print output after the loads statement either.

I've tried stripping the code to only the loads lines and including other code -- nothing runs.  If I comment out the pickle.loads line everything else runs as normal.  But I can't seem to de-serialize the byte stream.  try/except doesn't work either.

```
print('here') # This prints.
os.chdir(basedir+'Data/')
max_bytes = 2**31 - 1
bytes_in = bytearray(0)
input_size = os.path.getsize('[filename]')
with open('[filename]', 'rb') as f_in:
    for _ in range(0, input_size, max_bytes):
        bytes_in += f_in.read(max_bytes)

try:
    tmp_df = pickle.loads(bytes_in)
except:
    print('error') # This does not print.

print('loaded') # This does not print.
```

I'd expect an error message if there's something wrong, and the initial variables like `max_bytes` should remain loaded, but they all reset.  Instead:

```
In [1]: runfile('[file]', wdir='[dir')
   here

In [1]:
```

The variable explorer is blank and querying the variable names throws a `NameError`.

Comment: Does the problem occur if you run the code directly — i.e. without using iPython?

Comment: Thanks -- I'm not sure but I think it might have been an error in the file.  If re-pickle the data using simple pickle.dump I'm able to load it using pickle.load.  I haven't yet tried other large files that need to be serialized using dumps, fortunately this one is smaller.

Comment: Are you still using the same version of Python as before? The default pickle protocol [varies](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) depending on the exact version of the Python and module being used.